# Lagrange multipliers (with indices) and symmetries of effective action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics, effective-field-theory

I feel a bit embarrassed asking this, but I am a bit confused with this atm. I will try to skip most details and hopefully provide the essence of my question with clarity. Suppose there is an action functional $S$ which depends on two tensor fields, say the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and some other rank-$p$ tensor field $y_{\mu_1...\mu_p}$ as $S(g,\partial g,\partial^2g,y,\partial y)$, and to which we add an action involving a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_{\mu\nu...}(x)$ and a constraint $f^{\mu\nu...}(g,\partial g,y,z)$ such that the new action is
$$
\mathcal{S}=S+\int\mathrm{d}^4x\sqrt{-\det g}\lambda_{\mu\nu...}f^{\mu\nu...}.
$$
Here, $z$ is supposed to be a new tensor field. The ranks are in general unimportant for the question. It suffices that $\lambda f$ is obviously a coordinate scalar. The constraint equation does in the end fix $y$ as a function of $g,\partial g,z$. I also note here that in the particular case the $y$ equations of motion yield an exact expression for the Lagrange multiplier in terms of $g$, $\partial g$ and $z$.

First question: Does it matter what the canonical form of the multiplier is? By canonical form I mean the form by which $\delta_g\lambda=0$ (indices suppressed). I think it can be shown that which is the canonical form does of course alter the off-shell form of the metric field equations tensor, but on-shell, taking into account $f=0$ that is, it seems to be irrelevant because $\delta_{g}(\lambda f)=\lambda\delta_g f$ is always true subject to the constraint equation $f=0$, regardless of whether $\delta_g\lambda=0$ or not. However, the canonical form seems to play a role in the symmetry of the total action. As for example, consider that $S$ is invariant under local rescalings of the metric. There is indeed a possibility to find a combined symmetry under rescalings of $g$ and some infinitesimal transformations of $y$ and $z$, them being unimportant for our purposes. However this requires a certain canonical form for the multiplier defined in the beginning.

Second and third question (more general): clearly because $f$ depends on $\partial g$ the Lagrange multiplier is going to appear with a time derivative in the metric field equations. Does this mean that I have to be particularly cautious about some operation? Regardless of that I can always enforce the constraint $f=0$ in the action to obtain the effective beast. Is there a priori a relation between the symmetries of $S$, $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S_{eff}$ (I am not referring to diffeos here)? My first thought was that at best some or all initial symmetry is retained in the effective action, at worst all of this symmetry is broken. Is it possible that the effective action has "more"  symmetry than the initial one? However, thinking about it a second time, it also seems (to me) that there is no a priori relation, or an ``expected'' thing, rather everything is model dependent, and the symmetry of $\mathcal{S}_{eff}$ does not necessarily follow by some argument from that of $\mathcal{S}$ but rather is an accidental thing, in some cases perhaps justifiable but in general not. That is, one just has to enforce the constraint and simply look what symmetries $\mathcal{S}_{eff}$ enjoys. However this is a second point that really confuses me.

I am not of course expecting answers particular to this non-particular vague case I am describing. My questions as you hopefully see are a bit more general.